# Unable to Instal Mysql-connector Python2.0.2 for Python v3.4.2

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I have installed IDLE Python 3.4.2 & i want to install MySQL-Connector 2.7 for Python 3.4. I have downloaded mysql-connector 2.7 from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/. I have already tried to install this many a times but it always says "Python v3.4 is not found" even though it's already in the system & system path of Python is correct. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it should work

```
1. get python connector from MySQL  
2. unzip to a dir  
3. cd dir  
4. python setup.py install
```

In Step 4, it searches python command from system PATH and should be found. If not, then my guess is that Path is not properly set up

Comment: Thank you very much. I just re-installed the python & it worked.